# .bash_profile taking in quotes into beginning of alias

Tags: bash, alias

Here is a snippet from my .bash_profile:

```
    alias hi=“echo hi”
    alias oe=“open -e”
    alias u=“cd ..”
    alias uu="cd ../../“
    alias uuu=“cd ../../../“
```

If I attempt to run a command using an alias, a quote is inserted into the beginning of the command, so it fails:

```
    ~ tudanp$ hi
    -bash: “echo: command not found
```

I have tried both single and double quotes, quotes around the alias name, and no quotes around the command with none working (well, none around the command will insert everything before the first whitespace).  Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What are you using to edit the file? those look like unicode "smart" quotes - you need to replace them with regular ASCII quote characters

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, this is the solution.  I was using apple's text editor, when I clearly shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `.profile` in a text editor, and replace all of the `“`s with `"`s, and I think you'll be a happier camper.